# Android: xml won't update runtime no matter what changes

Tags: java, xml

Here's my xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="161dp"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/PopupCamera"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/camera" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/PopupFolder"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/folder" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

This is inside of a framelayout.
When I type on my .java:

```
Button mybutton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
```

Isn't this enough to make my button appear?
I don't understand why it won't show.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please add more code, with some screenshots of your output that what you getting and what your expecting. that will help us to solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: I noticed none of my changes do anything it just ignores my xml...

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with it reading the edited files.
So i changed the name of the xml I was editing and changed what xml i called in my .java and it worked!